# Empty database over 10GB in size

Tags: database, import, sql-server-express

While I was trying to populate a table from a 11GB text file (.tsv) I got the error:

> Could not allocate space for object 'X' in database 'Y' because the 'PRIMARY'
>       filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects
>       in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth
>       on for existing files in the filegroup.

I thought the problem was the database exceeded 10GB, [which is the limit for SQL Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159136/what-happens-when-you-hit-the-sql-server-express-4gb-10gb-limit). Yet, when I checked, I noticed the database is actually empty. The query

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Table
```

Takes several minutes to execute and it gives me back nothing. When I checked under properties > files I found out filegroup PRIMARY is actually 10240MB.

What is this about, and how can solve the problem?

Comment: It's time to look into the DBCC methods and shrink the database.  It is weird, though.  I had a case like that once where the log files had gotten to 50 GB or so and kept growing.

Answer (score 1):

Populating 11GB text file into SQL server express will give an error since it will exceed the edition limit. You either split the text file into 2 files or upgrade to standard edition. Or try Oracle XE? It store up to 11GB :) might be just enough for you.