# Restoring MSSQL SERVER database

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, database-restore

I have MSSQL SERVER 2008 R2 database running on my machine and trying to restore database using .bak file which is of 10.6 GB size but i am getting bellow error:-

```
       CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative
       database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB
```

and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version is 10.50.1617.0.

My questions are

1> How to increase the limit of SQL SERVER 2008 R2 .

2> Is there any other way to restore database? If it is not possible to increase the limit then which version of MSSQL SERVER  (free) should I download?

3> Is there any way to restore all the data in MySQL database directly because my final am to get all the data in MySQL database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159136/what-happens-when-you-hit-the-sql-server-express-4gb-10gb-limit

Comment: I have seen this post but I can not reduce the size of database, what should i do?

Comment: You're on the express version which has a size limit - pay for a licence and use the licence upgrade - easy.

Comment: Sharad, there is little you can do now. You cannot reduce the size of a database without connecting it to a server so you will need to restore this database to a fully licensed copy of MS SQL server, reduce it's size some how, back it up and then restore it to your Express version afterwards.

Comment: @Bridge thanks for reply but is there any other way to get all the data in MySQL database?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to restore to SQL Server Express and in 2008 it has a database limit of 10Gb (it used to be 4 GB).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answers regarding your queries.

1. How to increase the limit of SQL SERVER 2008 R2 .

Ans: There is only one way to increase the limit of MSSQL Server 2008 R2 that is you will have to upgrade it to the web edition version. In the web edition, you will get 524 PB database size.

2. Is there any other way to restore database? If it is not possible to increase the limit then which version of MSSQL SERVER (free) should I download?

Ans: No. It is not possible because the database size is around 10.6 GB and in Express edition you can create a database upto 10 GB only. There is no free version that offers you more than 10 GB database size.

If you want to increase the limit then you will have to go with Web edition. You can collect more details from the below URL:
https://www.znetlive.com/blog/feature-comparison-of-ms-sql-server-editions/

3. Is there any way to restore all the data in MySQL database directly because my final am to get all the data in MySQL database?

Ans: Yes, It is possible. You can use MySQL Workbench which provides a way to quickly migrate data and applications from Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL employing less time and effort.

This tool has a lot of cool features like:

Database migrations - enables migrations from Microsoft SQL Server, Sybase ASE and PostgreSQL.

Migration project management - allows migrations to be configured, copied, edited, executed and scheduled.

You can collect more details from this url http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/