# SQL Server Enterprise Timeout Exception when database size exceeds 10GB

Tags: sql-server, timeout

I'm getting SQL Timeout Exception when trying to update or insert new rows into database when database size exceeds 10GB while am using SQL Server Enterprise with no limit on database size, the problem disappears when deleting old records, then comes back when data size reaches 10GB again.

Comment: This is unlikely related to the engine edition. The symptoms suggest large scans by queries so the duration is proportional to the table size. Get the execution plan of a problem query, upload [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), and add that link to your question if you need help with tuning.

Comment: If it really happens exactly at 10 GB, then you probably don't have the "Enterprise" edition, but rather an **Express** edition installed (which has a limit at 10GB database size). Find out by running:  `SELECT @@VERSION`  against your database - what does it report back??

Comment: @marc_s, I think [a different error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159136/what-happens-when-you-hit-the-sql-server-express-4gb-10gb-limit) is raised if the db size limit is reached. Timeout errors occur on the client rather than the server.

Comment: Another possibility is the files are set to autogrow and the queries timeout because the growth takes too long. In that case, you can either enable [instant file initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization) or expand the file(s) manually so that no autogrow is required.

Comment: this is the result from query: SELECT @@VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @DanGuzman how can I expand the files manually?

Comment: @MoeSay, use T-SQL [ALTER DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options). This is an example from the documentation: `ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = test1dat3,
SIZE = 200MB);`